# How to make simple item checkout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make  simple item checkout for class but I can't figure out how to change the values of the items with the buttons. The provided code only makes the  "new-phone" item either 1 or -1. I have to use "item-state", and all the functions that were provided by my teacher. 
If anyone can explain how to use item-state or give me some advice on how to solve this problem it would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./items.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Items</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="items">
    <div class="rows">
      <label for="name">New Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="new-phone" id="new-phone" value="3">
      <span id="plus" class="material-icons" onclick="ItemStatusAdd()">add_circle</span>
      <span id="minus" class="material-icons" onclick="ItemStatusRemove()">delete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
      <label for="name">Toilet Paper</label>
      <input type="text" name="toliet-paper" id="toilet-paper" value="3">
      <span id="plus" class="material-icons" value="0">add_circle</span>
      <span id="minus" class="material-icons">delete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
      <label for="name">Grocer Package</label>
      <input type="text" name="grocer-package" id="grocer-package" value="3">
      <span id="plus" class="material-icons" value="0" >add_circle</span>
      <span id="minus" class="material-icons">delete</span>
    </div>

    <div id="item_status"></div>
  </form>
  <script src="items.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var item_state = [
  {
    title:"New Phone",
    num:0,
  },
  {
    title:"Toilet Paper",
    num:0,
  },
  {
    title:"Grocer Package",
    num:0

  }
]

function ItemUpdate(){
  //update the item UI with the item_state info
}

function ItemStatusAdd(item_index){
  var item_state = parseInt(document.getElementById('new-phone').nodeValue);
  item_state = isNaN(item_state) ? 0 : item_state;
  item_state++;
  document.getElementById('new-phone').value = item_state
  //add 1 to the num of item_state, and update the UI
}

function ItemStatusRemove(item_index){
  var item_state = parseInt(document.getElementById('new-phone').nodeValue);
  item_state = isNaN(item_state) ? 0 : item_state;
  item_state--;
  document.getElementById('new-phone').value = item_state
  //subtract 1 to the num of item_state, and update the UI
}
```

Comment: So you want to change the input field values when clicking the + button ?

Comment: Use `<button>` or `<input type="button">` instead of `<span>` for clickables

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You were using `.nodeValue`, when you should have been using `.value`. `.value` is the property to access on `<input>`s.

Here's your code with that change made, and your add/remove buttons work fine for phones.

```js
var item_state = [
  {
    title:"New Phone",
    num:0,
  },
  {
    title:"Toilet Paper",
    num:0,
  },
  {
    title:"Grocer Package",
    num:0

  }
]

function ItemUpdate(){
  //update the item UI with the item_state info
}

function ItemStatusAdd(item_index){
  var item_state = parseInt(document.getElementById('new-phone').value);
  item_state = isNaN(item_state) ? 0 : item_state;
  item_state++;
  document.getElementById('new-phone').value = item_state
  //add 1 to the num of item_state, and update the UI
}

function ItemStatusRemove(item_index){
  var item_state = parseInt(document.getElementById('new-phone').value);
  item_state = isNaN(item_state) ? 0 : item_state;
  item_state--;
  document.getElementById('new-phone').value = item_state
  //subtract 1 to the num of item_state, and update the UI
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./items.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Items</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="items">
    <div class="rows">
      <label for="name">New Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="new-phone" id="new-phone" value="3">
      <span id="plus" class="material-icons" onclick="ItemStatusAdd()">add_circle</span>
      <span id="minus" class="material-icons" onclick="ItemStatusRemove()">delete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
      <label for="name">Toilet Paper</label>
      <input type="text" name="toliet-paper" id="toilet-paper" value="3">
      <span id="plus" class="material-icons" value="0">add_circle</span>
      <span id="minus" class="material-icons">delete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
      <label for="name">Grocer Package</label>
      <input type="text" name="grocer-package" id="grocer-package" value="3">
      <span id="plus" class="material-icons" value="0" >add_circle</span>
      <span id="minus" class="material-icons">delete</span>
    </div>

    <div id="item_status"></div>
  </form>
  <script src="items.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```